# How to create a hibernate query with data from another object?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I need to create a Spring @Formula annotation that fills the PROPOSAL.USER_ID with the User ID {user.getId()} from the User object.

```
@Formula("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROPOSAL WHERE PROPOSAL.USER_ID = userId")
int numberOfProposals;
```

It does not work if I use ...

```
@Transient
private Long userId;
```

although it that has its getter and setter:

```
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public Proposal user(User user) {
    this.user = user;
    return this;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Long getUserId() {
    return this.user.getId();
}
```

And it does not work if I use:

```
@Formula("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROPOSAL WHERE PROPOSAL.USER_ID = ?#{this.user.id}")
```

Or:

```
@Formula("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PROPOSAL WHERE PROPOSAL.USER_ID = ?#{this.user.getId()}")
```

If there is any documentation that shows how, I would appreciate that.

Comment: And if you try with „... = user.id“?

Comment: No, it gives me an error.Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "USER.ID" not found. I think mndeveci is right in his comment down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basically not possible, because the member that you marked as `@Transient` is not accessible at database level. And the statement that is in `@Formula` annotation only runs at database level.

So they are part of different levels and you can not use each other.

What you can do is you can create a custom query and pass `userId` to that query in order to populate the entity classes.

Comment: Can you add the example with @Query? because IDE says: The annotation @Query is disallowed for this location. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you give more information about `userId` field and how its value is set, I could try to give an example, right now it is too blur for me.

Comment: It works with @Formula("SELECT SUM(number_of_points) FROM VOTE WHERE VOTE.USER_ID = USER_ID"). Just like that.

Comment: Ok but why are you setting `userId` as `@Transient`. Isn't that property should be mapped to `USER_ID` column too?

Comment: I was testing, but forget about it. it works changing userId for USER_ID (and not creating any Transient or anything)